# How to fast forward in YouTube app on iOS using bluetooth remote?

Tags: keyboard, accessibility, youtube, ios

I am using an ArcX (http://arcx.fit) bluetooth remote.

I want to be able to hold left/right arrow to fast-forward and rewind YouTube videos.

The commands sent when using the remote buttons can be rebound.

Does anyone know if the YouTube app listens to any keyboard shortcuts?

I am currently looking into [assistive touch accessibility options](https://support.apple.com/accessibility):

- Mouse Keys

  - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210546
  - https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mh27469/mac
- Gaming Controller support

  - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252118089

**UPDATE**

- Holding down a finger on the screen plays at 2x fast-forward.
- YouTube in Safari can listen to left and right arrows.
- iPadOS apparently responds to cmd+left/right and other shortcuts.
- There is a Premium feature called "Listening Controls" which puts the +/- 10s button on the screen for single touch - maybe this is addressable via SwitchControl or something.

Comment: What would you bind those keys to?  I’m not aware of *any* fast forward /rewind function in the YouTube app.

Comment: That’s my question. You can tap twice to skip forwards 10 seconds.

Comment: That’s not FF. Thats jump 10 seconds.  Are you asking how to bind keys to get something not actually available?

Comment: No, jump 10 seconds is what I am after.